# How do I fix the 1908 Virtualbox error?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, modprobe

I have the following error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package
and execute 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root.
```

This forbids me to launch any virtual machine.
I checked and I already have the `virtualbox-ose-dkms` package installed. As a matter of fact I reinstalled it too, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VirtualBox '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup' issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue)

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you had an update on virtualbox and because of that, its kernel module wasn't recompiled (that's why it wants you to install the dkms package).

I don't know if you're running the open source version of virtualbox, but usually running this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

solves the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Because of useful and regular updates it is recommended to install and run Virtual Box from the [repository maintained by Oracle](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). For avoiding to manually update the kernel driver on every update [DKMS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dkms) [image: Install dkms] is useful.

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487) for details on the installation of Virtual Box.

Comment: I had the same issue last night whenever I run VirtualBox.  I originally installed VirtualBox from Ubuntu Software Centre.  I have removed it, installed VirtualBox from Oracle and the issue has been resolved.  VirtualBox is now running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I had precisely the same error. Running `virtualbox` from the command-line gave the following error:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Consequently, I did the following and it solved the bug:

1. install the latest open-source version of VirtualBox as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487). Nonetheless, this step does not seem essential.
2. install the appropriate generic kernel header. As for me it was `linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic`. To know the version you need, you should type `uname -r` in a terminal.

Comment: The closed-source VirtualBox is not needed, installing the headers is enough ([related answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49059/unable-to-install-virtualbox-due-to-missing-kernel-module/49065#49065))