# VirtualBox '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup' issue

Tags: virtualbox, 12.10, virtualization

I have installed VirtualBox through the software centre, but when I try to start a VM, I get the following error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or
>   there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the
>   kernel module by executing
>
> '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'
>
> as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install
>   the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel
>   changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

I already updated my `dkms` and installed `linux-headers`, but this `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` doesn't exist.

I have been googling but I can't find an answer.

Comment: like others said, reinstall **"virtualbox-dkms"**

Comment: This happened to me after kernel update (ubuntu). For me it was just: "sudo apt-get install virtualbox". Installation process created kernel module for me.

Comment: The original post regards 12.10. If you are having this problem for 14.04, which may be more likely at the time of writing, use `virtualbox.org` instead of the one in `Ubuntu Software Centre`. The doc has long winded instructions but the following link is a shorter read. If you ignore the part about HTTPS then it is brief.  https://virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should peruse /var/log/vbox-install.log file to determine the issue. If the problem persists, you may want to download and install the latest v4.2.2 version directly from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads (for kernel 3.6.* and below). Good luck.

Comment: there is no freaking log file.... lol, I will just try the download from that site, I will be back to you when thats done and tested.

Comment: IC - no log file "can" be an issue. LOL

Comment: ok, I purged all the stuff I had, downloaded it from that site, and it started nicely, I am now installing an os, thanks mate!

Comment: Purging and installing the file from the `VirtualBox` official site did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the VirtualBox package in the repos is faulty. Evidently no one tests these packages...

Comment: Unfortunately even this does not work for me. I get the error: "Cannot install 'libpython2.7:i386'", but I already have libpython2.7 installed.

Comment: the answer by Jason Zhu works for me

Answer (score 132):

I also encountered this issue several times once I upgrade my linux kernel.

What I did:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Reconfigure dkms and load module:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms  
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

Then VirtualBox works. No computer reboot needed.

Comment: Just install the linux-headers as you pointed out, then `sudo ./etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` will take care of updating dkms.

Comment: `modprobe vboxdrv` Tells me: `FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.`

Comment: @pinouchon Did `dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` output any error messages?

Comment: I have to to this every few weeks or so, it seems, as I upgrade my system.  Any way to get it permanently fixed?

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie Maybe in your case it worked, but the OP clearly specifies that he already installed the headers, so I assume you didn't read the question.

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms

Comment: Osm, worked like charm :D
Thank you so0o much

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` didn't work for me (it was what VirtualBox suggested when it failed to restart a saved VM).
`dpg-reconfigure` followed by `modprobe` did.
(12.04 LTS, VirtualBox 4.1.12)

Comment: This got my vm starting, but with a network failure. After I do these steps I also need to `sudo modprobe vboxnetflt`

Comment: your answer is perhaps the most handy answer on the entire SE network to me, I've been using these commands, at least 4 times in the last 2 weeks

Comment: On 2015.04 I get `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: virtualbox-dkms is not installed`

Comment: Just executing `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms` works for me.

Comment: I had the same problem on Manjaro 17. `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` solves the problem. More info on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Install_the_core_packages

Answer (score 12):

Here's EXACTLY how to do it on 12.10:

Make sure there are no traces of dkms, (virtualbox/ virtualbox-4.2), linux generic headers (*.*.17):

***Replace virtualbox-4.2 with the version you have already installed. If you haven't installed it yet then proceed to step 2.

1. `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2 dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
2. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
3. `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2`

You MUST install the linux headers BEFORE virtualbox otherwise the VBox installation will error when trying to set up the vboxdrv section because the linux headers aren't installed.

Comment: Thanks but when I download virtualbox directly from the site, I don't have to do anything but 'sudo dpkg -i virtualbox.deb'. Less work.

Comment: then you are lucky! if you should need to mess about with linux headers at all then it's important to install them before virtualbox

Comment: Worked for me, afters hours of frustration. I am running ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This method worked for me. Downloading directly from the site did not. Basically, the headers is what's missing it seems. After installing the headers, as described above, I just installed vbox normally through the software centre.

Comment: Nice one Andre!

Comment: I used "sudo apt-get install virtualbox" and it worked great. thanks

Answer (score 9):

Reinstall "virtualbox-dkms"

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved with the installation of the kernel headers.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

After the installation of the headers, DKMS was set-up properly and Virtualbox just worked after a reboot.

Still, there is no vboxdrv in /etc/init.d.

Note: the package I initially installed was virtualbox (non ose):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this before posting my question, but it didnt work. The answer I selected as "The answer" is selected because the install from the site worked, and I would not have thought of it, since I thought it were the same files.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen No problem :)! Installing the headers and rebooting worked for me, but maybe I had some other packages installed that made the difference (even if I installed vbox as one of the first packages after a clean installation of 12.10).

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and encountered exactly this problem. I did all the recommended stuff listed here (uninstall, re-install headers, dkms, etc) and still couldn't get it to work.

What finally worked was going to the virtualbox website (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), downloading the package and installing it via:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.2_4.2.10-84104~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

And it worked like a charm.

Comment: top most answer says the exact same thing.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Just re-read the first post and you're right. But i had like 3 or 4 tabs open researching for the answer so I was skimming through posts and trying things out and I think I was mildly frustrated so I missed the second part of his answer. Anyway, I also posted this as a more thorough instruction for the beginner (like me) who can't remember simple stuff like how do I install a .deb package. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 12.04 I was not able to solve it via standard repositories. I had to download Virtualbox from its website and use version 4.3

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox Installation

Open the terminal and issue these commands for Ubuntu 12.10/Linux Mint:

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-4.2
```

Web: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/virtualbox-424-released-ppa.html

Answer (score 0):

what i found instead is that if you run

```
# modprobe vboxdrv
```

before running virtualbox, you will not have that sign

so I just add

```
 vboxdrv
```

in     /

```
 /etc/modules
```

which is equivalent to run

```
  'modprobe vboxdrv'
```

after system start

Comment: Bad advice.. This is handeled by the `/etc/init.d/virtualbox` script. Adding it here makes it redundant and harder to maintain and manage.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**
If you have not yet installed DKMS run this command

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

If is already installed resintallation should fix the problem

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

**2)** After the (re)installation process you should see something similar to this

---

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-61-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-61-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.........

DKMS: install completed.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
Setting up virtualbox-qt (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.10) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

---

**3)** Close VirtualBox and wait for at least 10 seconds for the daemon to shutdown.

**4)** Open VirtualBox again and Start the machine, it should be fixed