# Virtualbox and Header Updates

Tags: updates, kernel, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and VirtualBox 4.1.12

The last 3 (Header) updates have resulted in VirtualBox not working immediately after the header update.

I searched this forum and found [this discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue/337042#337042). Using VedVals answer of Dec 1, '12 the situation was resolved.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how overcome this issue, so that after the Headers are updated VirtualBox will just function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue that [dates back to Ubuntu 11.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885936) at least. It happens regularly, although less frequently now, but you'll always have to repair the headers manually. The quickest way of doing it is by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

You can also create an alias for these commands as shown [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885936&p=12598521#post12598521).

Comment: When you say " ... this will always happen ...", then why? 

The problem is that when there are many machines to update, (and some of those machines are remote) then consequence (ie, possibility of errors) can be quite expensive and disruptive.