# VirtualBox Drive Error (kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) )

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

So, I am using a Thinkpad by lenovo. I have been upgrading it every year, and it runs Very good for its model age. I have Installed VirtualBox On my system. I like crunchbang because of its style. So, what i did with VirtualBox is that I Made a Virtual Machine for Windows 7 In VirtualBox. Everytime I Start It, the same

```
"kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)" Error
```

comes up. I have tried the `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`
Command, and nothing works. the terminal Refuses it, and says that the command is not a Command. I'm Actually Trying to use VirtualBox to DJ With Virtual DJ. Icecasting doesnt work on linux, so that is the reason why i was trying to make a Windows 7 Virtual Machine. Please Help, I'm only 14, and my knowledge of the internet is Very big, But my knowledge of Errors is really shitty. Thank you
-Ray

Answer (score 0):

Did you search on here for this error? There are a large number of answers to this question eg [VirtualBox '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup' issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue)

Comment: i'm about to lol.. :)