# Virtual box not running - '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup' issue

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

Before asking i have checked [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed) and [VirtualBox '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup' issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue), i have exactly same issue and have reinstalled VB also,

output of running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` is shown below :

```
------------------------------ 
Deleting module version: 4.1.12 completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------ 
Done. Loading new virtualbox-4.1.12 DKMS files... Building only for 3.5.0-47-generic Building initial module for 3.5.0-47-generic 
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.5.0-47-generic (i686) 
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
```

**make.log**

> DKMS make.log for virtualbox-4.1.12 for kernel 3.5.0-47-generic (i686)
>   Thu Apr  3 21:37:08 IST 2014 make: Entering directory
>   `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-47-generic'   LD
>
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/built-in.o   LD
>
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o   CC [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
>
>   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o   CC
>   [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o   CC
>   [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
>   CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
>
>   CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
>
>   CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
>   CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
>   CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
>   CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
>   CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
>   CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjLinuxDoMmap’:
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1150:9:
>   error: implicit declaration of function ‘do_mmap’
>   [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration] cc1: some warnings being
>   treated as errors make[2]: ***
>   [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o]
>   Error 1 make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv]
>   Error 2 make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build]
>   Error 2 make: Leaving directory`
>   /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-47-generic'

If someone has faced same situation...please help me out!!

Comment: post the contents of `/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log` file.

Comment: Yeah the last line should be a clue that there's more you could do :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj : added....does it help?? :)

Comment: @Oli : i suspect it has something to do with `vboxdrv`

Comment: have you installed VB from repository, or directly from [VB](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)'s site ? from my memory, the second's choice works better.

Comment: **someone.....any one.......no one with answer???**

Comment: @FredB. : not from repository but vb site....thru terminal commands!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no helpful answer is found, here is what helped me... :

uninstall the exisiting VB :

```
  sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
```

**Dependency**

First install the dependency package to avoid error.**

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

**To add PPA**

Open a `terminal` and run the following command to download and  install the key from Oracle. Issue the password for the user when prompted.

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

After installing the Oracle public key, use the below command to add it to your repository.

For Ubuntu 13.10

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian saucy contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
```

For Ubuntu 13.04

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
```

For Ubuntu 12.10

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
```

For Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
```

For Ubuntu 11.10

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
```

For Ubuntu 11.04

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian natty contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
```

Once you added the repo using the above command, 
**Update your repository.**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**To Install**

Now install the virtualbox 4.3 using the below command.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

To install the previous version just replace 4.3 to 4.2 / 4.1 / 4.0 / 3.2 in the above command.

**To Open**

Go to dash and type `Virtualbox`, click on the icon.

here is  [**source url**](http://www.howopensource.com/2013/04/install-virtualbox-ubuntu-ppa/)