# /etc/init.d/vboxdrv missing

Tags: virtualbox

When I try to launch a virtual machine from Virtualbox, it tells me that the Virtualbox kernel driver is not loaded, or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv.

> Please reinstall the kernel module by executing `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` as root.

It also tells me that I should install the DKMS package first (which I have done).

Now, the mentioned files to not exist in my system. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you reinstall Virtual Box? I haven't used VM programs in a while, so I don't really know what's going on with them.

Comment: Is there anything you did which you believe may have caused this?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I tried reinstalling and it still is missing.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I do not recall anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup' issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. You may try to include Orace's VirtualBox repository as described in [1]. Before you have to uninstall virtualbox (apt-get remove virtualbox). Then you have /etc/init.d/vboxdrv and can use it to recompile the virtualbox drivers in case DKMS fails.

[1] https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

If not, run these commands to run an update and reinstall the linux-headers and virtualbox-dkms

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms
```

Reboot and then:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```