# cleaning up from trials to setup VirtualBox from Ubuntu Software Centre in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (2015 September) and I used `Ubuntu Software Centre` to install VirtualBox. I encountered this error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not 
loaded or there is a permission
problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module 
by executing
'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'
as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the 
DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes
and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
```

To deal with this problem, I first used

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

When that did not fix VirtualBox, I tried various fixes suggested at this link:

[question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue)

What are the adverse consequences for having tried the most popular answer:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms  
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

and the adverse consequences of having tried this suggestion from a less popular answer:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

Epilogue: I used `Ubuntu Software Centre` to uninstall VirtualBox and then I used the instructions from the `virtualbox.org` to successfully install it. However, I am still interested in the adverse effects of the trial and error activities. Should Ubuntu be reinstalled to clean up the effects of the trial and error activity?

Comment: In my experience virtualbox complained about dkms being unable to build module for the latest kernel but older kernel like 3.13 worked. The way i fixed it is by installing  virtualbox from the official site. You may wanna try the same. Virtualbox in Ubuntu repository may be dated or something

Answer (score 1):

There are no adverse effects to action you took and all of them were necessary.
Let's see them in detail,

---

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

This command installs linux headers which are a requirement for virtualbox. `uname -r` portion here give name and version of your os, you could even type it in a terminal to check output yourself.

---

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
```

This command reconfigured `virtualbox-dkms` package. Normally a package gets configure at its install time but since you already had `virtualbox-dkms` package, you had to use `dpkg-reconfigure`.

---

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

This `modprobe` command here is used to set kernel modules. Virtualbox requires `vboxdrv` kernel module, thats why you have to `modprobe` it. Try `man modprobe` to find more about it.

---

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

This command simply reinstalled virtualbox-dkms package. This command also has no adverse effect but it makes `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` useless since package `virtualbox-dkms` will be reinstalled anyway so we dont need to reconfigure it.

Hope that clears it up :).
Also On a sidenote do run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` that will remove any left redundant package with it settings. If you want to get rid of apt cache you could also do `apt-get clean`.