# Virtualbox stopped runnuing after new kernal install

Tags: 18.04

I am using Vbox on a Ubuntu host to run Arca Noae 503. Currently when starting the virtual machine of Arca Noae, I am getting an error message that the Vbox Linux driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv, the Vbox version is 6.0.4 r128413 (qt 5.9.5). The host is Ubuntu 18.04 on kernel 5.3.0-28 loaded on 01/17/20. The install of Vbox ran fine on 01/15/20.  The error message indicates to run /sbin/vboxconfig as root which I have however it fails with the message “vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong”, however I am unable to find in the log what to do differently. The file “vboxdrv.sh” permissions are root and executable. The error message also notes that there are permission problems with /dev/vboxdrv, however I can not find vboxdrv.sh in that path.

Thanks for all of the suggestions. I added Virtualbox to the Debian sources list so that Vbox will update in the future when a new versions is released. I then installed version 6.1 and resolved all of the questions related to guest additions. The new install is working well and resolved all of the issues.

Comment: When I have troubles like this I purge my installed virtualbox and re-install from here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads.

Comment: Are you a member of the vboxusers group? if not then `usermod -a -G vboxusers [USERNAME]`

Comment: After reading again I see that you have been using vbox already. So  that may not be you problem

Comment: Please edit your question to add paragraphs - the wall of text is hard to read. Also, please clearly explain --step by step-- how you originally installed Virtualbox. It's clear that you didn't use the version in the Ubuntu Repositories, so we don't know what mistake or shortcut then is biting you now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup' issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205154/virtualbox-etc-init-d-vboxdrv-setup-issue)

Comment: How did you install the new kernel?  I'd say that anything else than `apt-get install` or `apt install` will cause you trouble, "don't do that" if you're an inexperienced user (= not aware of the plausible problems that come of it).

Answer (score 0):

Update Virtualbox version (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or downgrade kernel version

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.0

> VirtualBox 6.0.14 (released October 15 2019): support Linux 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the suggestions. I added Virtualbox to the Debian sources list so that Vbox will update in the future when new versions are is a new relase. I then installed version 6.1 and resolved all of the questions related to guest additions. The new install is working well and resolved all of the issues.