# Downloading Error while installing VirtualBox Guest Additions

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed Windows7 as guest in my Ubuntu 11.10 host using virtualBox.

Now the problem is when I try to install the *VirtualBox Guest Additions* I am getting the following error.

[image: Screen Shot1]

[image: Screen Shot 2]

Comment: Which version of VBox? And the Oracle one, or the OSE? For the latter you need to install the package `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`.

Comment: Virtual Box has quite a lot of useful updates that increase performance and stability (at the moment version 4.1.8). Therefore I recommend you install it directly from the [Oracle repository](http://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940), where you can get both the Open Source version and additional closed source (PUEL) extensions for USB2.0, RDP, and PXE boot support. This will always include most recent Guest Additions as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could install Guest Additions from terminal, using this command:

```
 sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this same error and then realized that I needed to explicitly tell Ubuntu Software Center to install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso.