# Installing drivers for a windows 7 guest in virtualbox

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, 10.10, windows-7, hardware

I am new to ubuntu. I want to know how to install drivers such as lan, wifi, audio, video & graphics, webcam and so in Windows 7 32bit installed as a guest OS inside Ubuntu 10.10 (host) using Virtual Box 3.2.8.

I am using this in a Toshiba Satellite c650 psc 14g. I had downloaded the drivers from the Toshiba website. They work fine when using Windows 7 32 bit as host OS.

Then what are the main differences between dual boot and Virtual Box?

Answer (score 2):

System inbuilt components like LAN, Wifi, soundcard,or graphics card will be used from the host OS. They will be virtualized using an emulation for the guest OS. In many cases you are able to choose from different emulation modes in the virtual machine settings.

> Therefore you can not install these drivers to your guest OS.

However some external components like USB attached devices (e.g. printer, scanner, Bluetooth dongle) do need an additional driver for the guest OS. In Windows you will be asked for these drivers as soon as you capture the device from the Virtual Box Manager.

**Note:** for full USB 2.0 support we need to run the [PUEL version of Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940) that to date is on version 4.1.8.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (and you can't) install your real hardware drivers inside VirtualBox. Windows, while running inside VirtualBox can't access your hardware, it can only interact with a *Virtual* (false) hardware that VirtualBox will set for it. Virtual Box will translate it to the real hardware. You can get a more complete explanation of how virtual machines work in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).

That it's the reason that you can't really play the latest games under Virtual Box. Nor the game, nor Windows can access your graphics card to get the most speed. This is also the reason why **running windows under a virtual machine is slower than running it on bare metal**.

But you will need to install the drivers for the *Virtual Hardware* to get the best experience possible. They are called Guest Additions in Virtual Box, check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox) to install them.

Note that the virtual machine has no direct access to your card, so watching HD videos or playing 3D games can't be accelerated by it and it will be slower than doing it in the host. As you experienced, the speed will be similar to the one that you see while using windows without the drivers (i.e. using no video card acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you wont need to install any drivers as windows will automatically detect the emulated hardware and install the required drivers. As windows is running on virtual box so it needs the drivers for emulated hardware and not your actual hardware. Mapping emulated hardware to real is the job of VirtualBox and Winodws is not aware that it is running on emulated hardware.

Comment: why are you watching videos in guest? why dont you use host i.e ubuntu for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to Install Anything in the Windows guest, Windows installs it automatically.

And the difference between Dual Boot and Emulated Hardware are just...to many, for one it will be slower in the Virtual Machine, you don't have complete 3D hardware acceleration, nor you can't access directly your physical hardware from the Virtual Machine.

The Virtual Machine is as fast as your real hardware can handle it and judging by the Lack of Specs and looking at the Basic Toshiba laptop i would just install Windows side by side with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr host OS
VirtualBox 4.3.10Ubuntu r93012 
Windows 7 Home Premium guest

I had the same problem. I first burned the .iso file to a DVD and set up passthrough access to the CD/DVD drive on my Toshiba Satellite C660 laptop. (But you probably don't need to do this; just use the .iso file and mount it as a DVD.) The Windows 7 folder for the VM was created, and the Windows 7 installer started okay. But just after I clicked Start Setup, a dialogue asked "Where do you want to install Windows?, and displays the virtual VDI volume.

After I clicked Next, a dialogue asked me to select drivers, but the list was blank. When I chose either the DVD .iso or the virtual VDI drive, an alert advised that no drivers were found.

The answer is to change the permissions of /home/<~my-home>/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7/ and its subsidiary files and folders to Read/Write for owner and group (or even for everybody if it's your own computer). The installer hummed along doing its thing happily.