# Is virtual box as effective as dual booting windows?

Tags: virtualbox

Is virtual box as effective as dual booting windows? If I am able run windows in linux and do everything I can in windows I might as well as get rid of win 8.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133845/deciding-between-virtual-machine-or-dual-boot-setup

Comment: It depends on what it is that you do, but if you want a general answer; no, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The only downfall is you have to share ram when running a virtual machine. You can actually dual boot within the virtual machine as well.

It's far safer testing in a vm than actually dual booting, but as far as effectiveness, really depends on what you want to do as [Jo-Erlend Schinstad](https://askubuntu.com/users/19779/jo-erlend-schinstad) already said.