# Dual-boot or Windows Virtualization?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, virtualization

#### Do I use dual-boot or Windows Virtualization on Ubuntu?

## TL;DR

I am learning how to program and Ubuntu OS, so a Virtualization of Ubuntu on Windows was enough. However, when writting a program to access the Network Card or GPU or another hardware, It wasn't possible. It is a Virtual Machine limitation.

So I read a lot of Dual-Boot vs. Virtualization and learned that it depends on your needs.

The option of Dual-boot seemed the right choice. But the official Ubuntu Doc [WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) says:

> This page describes how to set up your computer in order to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows. Warning /!\ While there are some benefits to dual-booting (e.g. better performance for a native install), **it is not recommended**. Instead, it is best to do a native install of Ubuntu, and then virtualize the other operating system.

So as a newbie I got confused.

#### Question

Which is a better choice: **Dual-boot** or **Virtualize Windows on Ubuntu?**

When there are 3D softwares/gaming that must run on Windows and Linux is needed for programming (directly access hardwares and performance for deep learning).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deciding between virtual machine or dual-boot setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133845/deciding-between-virtual-machine-or-dual-boot-setup)