# What is the recommended settings to set to Linux with Windows as primary operating system?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, bios

I actually have a 1 TB HDD and I already split the drive in half for both OSes. Windows 7 is already set to 500 GB and the remaining space will be for Linux Ubuntu. (This is not the problem I am running into however).

When comes the time to install Linux Ubuntu, there is the point where I am stuck...

I would like to know what are the settings I should **put at Linux Ubuntu as main OS** so I can **jump to Windows 7** whenever I want and **go back to Linux Ubuntu** whenever I want **when I'm on Windows 7**.

Comment: "What is the recommended settings" There is no recommedation, only what you feel it should be. The only size you need to adhere to is the size the install base needs and the personal data you need to keep. Generally 20Gb for / is more than enough for Linux but the amount of personal data you want to keep is up to you. A 20Gb disk you use for watching video can work but at some point you need to delete video's. With 1000Tb the need to do that is 50000 times less.

Comment: If you want to use Linux from inside Windows (or vice versa), you should use Virtualization (e.g. `Virtual Box`)

Comment: We all agree that we are not sure of what you want. Can you be more specific? Do you know what dual boot is? Is dual boot what you are after, or is it virtualization?

In brief (and simplified a bit), Virtualization is runing na Operating System inside another operating system, so you can have both at the same time. 

With Dual Boot you have two Operating Systems installed independently, and you have to choose which one to use when you turn on the computer. To use the other system, you'll have to turn off (or restart) the computer and then turn it on again, so you can choose again.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deciding between virtual machine or dual-boot setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133845/deciding-between-virtual-machine-or-dual-boot-setup)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "recommended" settings. What is happening when you dual boot, is that you split your Hard Drive in whatever size partitions you like, and then you install both the operating systems. Then a boot loader (`grub` most possibly in your case) will prompt you as to what OS you would like for it to start loading. Once you are inside the OS, the "settings" of the hard drive's partition sizes, no longer effect your performance (I assume of course that you have given enough space to Windows and Linux, for it to operate normally).

Personally, since Linux is not as HD hungry as Windows (but again, depends), I would given the majority of the HD at Windows (70~80%) and i would use Windows's space, from inside Linux, to store data. That 20~30% of HD that Linux will get, seems a pretty good amount for it.

Comment: That's what I do also, in dual boot machines: a few GBs for the Linux System and use the NTFS partition for shared data between Windows and Linux. But, for me at least, it does not make sense to have dual boot machines nowadays. I usually install Linux as the base system and Virtualize Windows. For Internet and Office everyday stuff I rarely boot Windows.

Comment: It is a huge topic as to what a dual boot machine can offer that Virtualization can't. But indeed for the average usage, Virtualization has come a long way for dual boot to still be that famous.

Answer (score 2):

## There is no such thing as "optional partition".

Once you install Ubuntu along side Windows 7. You will have to **reboot** your computer every time you want to switch between Ubuntu and Windows.

When you reboot the computer, you will see a (grub) menu that will let you choose between Ubuntu and Windows. If you don't select anything, grub will wait a few seconds and continue to boot Ubuntu.

If you want to "jump" to Windows, you will have to **restart** the computer, and choose "Windows" from the grub menu. When you are done with Windows, and want to "jump" back to Ubuntu, you will have to **restart the computer again**.

Hope this helps

Comment: E.g. I'm actually on Ubuntu, I click on an icon, then it put Ubuntu in standby and start Windows 7. Then if I want to go back to Ubuntu I do the same thing. Could it be possible to do that?

Comment: No. That is not possible. If you have a powerful computer with lots of RAM, you can run one operating system inside the other in a virtual computer. The virtual computer won't use the full power of the real computer.