# Having trouble using Ubuntu 12.04 ISO in Virtual Box

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, virtualization

I followed step-by-step from this site :

[Installing Ubuntu inside Windows using VirtualBox](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox)
This is my system info:

> > > > System Information
> > > >         -———————-
> > > >         Time of this report: 11/14/2012, 22:40:29
> > > >         Machine name: CHRISTOPHER-PC
> > > >         Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1   (7601.win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506)
> > > >         Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
> > > >         System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
> > > >         System Model: System Product Name
> > > >         BIOS: BIOS Date: 02/05/10 19:13:52 Ver: 08.00.10
> > > >         Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
> > > >         Memory: 8192MB RAM
> > > >         Available OS Memory: 8174MB RAM
> > > >         Page File: 2227MB used, 14117MB available
> > > >         Windows Dir: C:\Windows
> > > >         DirectX Version: DirectX 11
> > > >         DX Setup Parameters: Not found
> > > >         User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
> > > >         System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
> > > >         DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
> > > >         DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 64bit Unicode
> > > >         DxDiag Previously: Crashed in Direct3D (stage 2). Re-running DxDiag with “dontskip” command line parameter or choosing not to bypass information gathering when prompted might result in DxDiag successfully obtaining this information

I get the following VirtualBox Error:
        Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu 64bit.

```
    VT-x features locked or unavailable in MSR. 
    (VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED).

    Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
    Component: Console
    Interface: IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
```

I have no idea what's going on.  I got Ubuntu up on running on my laptop, but I just got a desktop and I can't seem to get it working.

Downloaded ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386 from [Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (Precise Pangolin)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/)

Comment: you should try going into your bios settings and see if virtualization is enabled. Cause that's a virtualbox error message not ubuntu. And I think VT-x features are cpu virtualization features. But you can look it up in the virtualbox settings.

Answer (score 3):

For optimal performance of Virtual Box we need to enable VT-x (on Intel systems) or AMD-V (for AMD systems) in our BIOS settings in case our CPU has this feature.

To use this virtualization technology we then can enable this in the system settings for a virtual machine from Virtual Box Manager (*Settings -> System -> Acceleration*).

By doing so we are even able to run a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit host.

The architecture of the virtual machine (32- *vs.* 64-bit) also needs to be defined in the machine's *General* settings. In your case when installing the **-i386**-version this would be 32-bit (for 64-bit use the **-amd64**-images).

See also the following question: [amd64 virtual machine in virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128830/amd64-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

On my [new] HP Envy Phoenix (h9-1420t) I was surprised to find this BIOS setting in:

Security -> System Security -> Virtualization Technology (VTx/VTd)  > disabled

Answer (score 0):

The Virtualbox error reported is related to VTx functionality in the host machine BIOS - check that VTx is enabled there (not in the guest machine virtual bios)

Important note: - in some buggy BIOSes, it may help to try setting it both on or off (it should really be enabled) if this does not work as expected - my HP workstation BIOS is buggy like this - the host BIOS displays it wrongly.

Once VTx is correctly enabled, it should be possible to use more than one virtual processor when running in a VTx enabled multicore host. It should also be possible to run 64bit guest machines on a 32 host, but again, only if VTx is enabled on the host.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are using more than one CPU or processor in your virtual machine. Open it again and retry. Setting -> System -> Processor

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that using the escape key and then pressing f10 key. The BIOS menu came.

Answer (score -3):

You have to be an administrator to run Virtualbox. Right click and choose "Run as administrator"

Comment: While this is about a windows host system, I doubt very much that running virtualbox as administrator is the sensible thing to do.

Comment: @guntbert Agreed. Many Windows users run with administrative accounts all the time, but the risk is now somewhat mitigated by [User Account Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_account_control). I've run VirtualBox and VMware in Windows 7 and 8, which have UAC (and I had it enabled in both). I have never had to use the "Run as administrator" option to virtualize a guest with either. *Installing* software requires acting as an administrator. Occcasionally on some systems *configuring* virtual hardware settings requires acting as an administrator. Actually running a VM does not.