# Why ubuntu cannot work in virtualbox?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I've installed virtualbox on my laptop which has Windows 7 operating system, but I cannot run Ubuntu and it shows me the following error:

> This kernel requires a x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>   Unable to boot- use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

Comment: Add your system specs here, specifically what kind of processor do you have?

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://askubuntu.com/a/128846/3940