# Unable to run Ubuntu on Virtual box: Kernel require X86-6PU

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vmware, architecture

I am trying to install Ubuntu on oracle virtual box but I am not able to. I tried the same about a year back and it worked like a charm.

Here are the details:

1) Installed oracle virtual box version 4.2.10 r84104

2) Ubuntu iso image

My system details:

```
Processor :- Intel core 2 Duo T6500 @ 2.10 GHZ
RAM :- 4 GB
OS :- Windows 7 Home Premium
System type :- 64-bit Operating system
Intel(r) 64 Architecture :- Yes (got this information from Intel processor identification utility, downloaded from Intel website. )
Intel(R) Virtual Technology :- No
```

Every-time, I try to install Ubuntu on oracle virtual box or using VMWare player or VMWare workstation, I get the error message as:

```
This Kernel requires a x86-64 CPU,But detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot, please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

Comment: this may answer your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128830/amd64-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox

Comment: Also it seems you have Intel Virtualization technology disabled: that should not be required to VirtualBox to run, but it should give better performance. So if performance becomes a problem, check your BIOS settings.