# Using Oracle VirtualBox to boot Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: system-installation

I booted it up then selected the language but then it says `This Kernel requires a x86-64 CPU. Unable to boot.`

Comment: You *seriously* need to talk about what host os version and arch, and system you are using to get a more complete answer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128830/amd64-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox - you have to define a 64-bit environment in the general settings of your VM.

Answer (score 0):

```
This Kernel requires a x86-64 CPU. Unable to boot.
```

That means you are trying to install 64-bit server in a 32-bit CPU.  The Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit download link not placed in main download page.

You can get Ubuntu 13.10 server 32-bit [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-server-i386.iso)

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings / General / Basic (tab), what Ubuntu version did you specify? It should be Ubuntu (64 bit). If it's just Ubuntu, this would be one reason for the error. Also there's a possibility that you need to turn on, in your BIOS settings, Intel Virtualization Technology (IVT) or AMD-V depending.