# Need help running Ubuntu on Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I've been using Windows for years and thought I'd give Linux a try. As listed in the title, I'm trying to run Ubuntu through Oracle's Virtual box. When I go to the Install for Ubuntu, I get a black screen saying that the kernel version I am currently using is i686 rather than the x86-64 CPU...

Where do I go from here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is installing Ubuntu on my VirtualBox not successful?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/why-is-installing-ubuntu-on-my-virtualbox-not-successful) or http://askubuntu.com/questions/128830/amd64-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox (for 64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

download a 64bit version of ubuntu and try again

Comment: I've downloaded the 64 bit version. I've gone through my settings on virtual box and find no where where I can switch the architecture over to a 86-64 system. I'm about to try the 32 bit version.