# How to not install virtualbox addition in ubuntu-server 12.04?

Tags: server, virtualbox, guest-additions

First when I finished installing ubuntu-server 12.04, I made a snapshot then I updated my server like so

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I think the guest addition via the ubuntu-repository is buggy. Because after I rebooted I couldn't see in my virtualbox-ubuntu-server-12.04 window. It was just black. I am following [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-11.10-ispconfig-3-p3) tutorial and it said I need to update my server.

That means I will get the virtualbox guest additions from the ubuntu-repository.

How can I update upgrade my Ubuntu server 12.04 without installing the guest addition from the Ubuntu-repository?

Comment: can i remove guest addition link in the sources list? or what i really want is to just skip the guest additions and installed all the remaining updates

Answer (score 8):

Virtual Box guest additions do not install per default. We do have to manually install them as outlined here:

- [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox)

In a non-GUI (server) guest we may not need the guest additions if we do not need additional features provided with them (e.g. support for USB2). Then we simply do not install the guest additions that come on an .iso image **installed on the host** after installing the virtualbox-guest-additions-iso package there with

```
user@host:$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions
```

When having installed the version from the Oracle repository (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox)) the guest additions .iso is installed on the host by default.

Installing guest additions is done from an install script on the .iso to compile and  insert the kernel modules provided. Mounting the .iso image can be done from their location on the host, or alternatively by installing the guest additions .iso from the Ubuntu repository with

```
user@guest:$ sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install virtualbox-guest-additions
```

<sup>We should not install recommends in the guest to avoid installing virtualbox-ose package too.</sup>

Note that the guest-additions version from the repositories may be of an earlier version than Virtual Box when installed from Oracle. This will likely work but it is not recommended.

After having installed the kernel modules guest additions .iso can be removed from the guest OS. To uninstall guest additions from the guest we may remove the kernel modules manually, or run the `uninstall.sh` script located in `/opt/<VirtualBoxAddtions-x.x.xx>/`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong command, should be:

> sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

Answer (score 0):

You may install the VirtualBox extensions from the Ubuntu or from the Oracle/Virtualbox repositories.

- You may check: [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack)

Note that the installation of the extensions may require to re-compile the extensions using the DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) or to re-compile the kernel your machine uses. In Ubuntu, you must install `dkms` before.

```
# install dkms if you haven't already
sudo apt install dkms
```