# how to use ubuntu server virtualization feature?

Tags: server, virtualization

I have downloaded and installed ubuntu 11.10 server on a high end dell power edge server.
i have another desktop for my development which is windows 7

How do I create VM's etc on ubuntu 11.10 server ? I would like to do it from my development desktop i mean all the VM management etc from Windows 7

Can someone suggest which would be better option ? I am new to Virtualisation , i want some simple GUI based tools to do , am not a CLI Geek .

Regards
sashank

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible to run a virtual machine on a remote server without the need of installing a GUI there to control and manage the VM. You can even create a virtual machine on your Windows desktop to export it to the server, run it there, and use your Windows for display of the VM. However you will need a cross-platform solution that will run on both Windows, and Ubuntu.

In case you want to try out [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) you will need the closed source (PUEL) but free version available from Oracle (see [this question on how to install for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487) and the user manual for [installation on Windows](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#installation_windows)) to get support for the Virtual Box remote desktop display feature.

There is a nice tutorial from the Virtual Box user manual on [how to set this up](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) and how to run virtual box in "headless" mode on a server to use a remote machine's display via VRDP.