# How to install Hasselblad Phocus on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, photography

I am a photographer and I have recently switched to Ubuntu.
I used to use Hasselblad's Phocus on my Windows PC and I would like 
to continue to use it here as well.
I have already installed wine but the programme's installation fails every single time I try.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Unless Hasselblad publishes a version running natively in Ubuntu (don't hesitate to ask them) there is no way to get the proprietary Windows and MacOS only **Phocus**-software running in near professional usability.

In case you really need this very software (e.g. for Hasselblad specific image processing) you may want to consider running in with Windows in a virtual machine (e.g. [VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487)). Any windows software can be seamlessly integrated with the Ubuntu desktop but you should not expect it to run as smooth and fast as it did on your non-virtualized Windows machine.

#### [Gimp](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gimp&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

You may already use this powerful image processing software that can (and needs to) be highly customized with a [variety of plugins](http://registry.gimp.org/). GIMP 2.8.x+ is compatible with latest versions of UFRaw.

#### [Darktable](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=darktable&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

This ambitious software is aimed at the need of photographers. There are [many features](https://www.darktable.org/) including RAW image processing (but I have no experience if Hasselblad is supported, if not then do ask the developers if this can be made possible).

[image]

Comment: Well, Darktable is good, but it crashes a lot on my pc.

Comment: There is a (solved) issue with Unity 5.12 (see: http://www.darktable.org/2012/07/fixed-darktable-crashing-unity/). In case of bugs it may be worth to also try the latest (unstable) release from **ppa:pmjdebruijn/darktable-unstable** - but be warned unstable releases may also introduce new bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the answer, but would you care to try UFRaw? [image: Screenshot]

http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/Install.html
It can also be installed directly from the Ubuntu Software Center...

Comment: If not... http://www.codeweavers.com/services/ could be your answer.

Comment: I have tried it but it does not appeal to me