# What kind of photo-editing software can be used in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

What kind of photo editing software can I use for Ubuntu? Does Ubuntu support PHOTOSCAPE? I'm more familiar with this.

Comment: See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211542/how-to-install-hasselblad-phocus-on-ubuntu-12-04) here. Darktable is specifically aimed at photo processing.