# How to install VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and I want to install VirtualBox in Ubuntu through terminal. Can you guys please provide me the command to install it?

Comment: For the closed source version see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox

Answer (score 14):

Virtualbox is in the official repository.

Just open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

After installing you should add the user, you want to use VirtualBox with to the vboxusers group by:

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

If you prefer a more recent version, take a look at [Download VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Help page from the Oracle VM virtualbox website.
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions

It has a list of deb packages you can download.

You can run it with

```
sudo dpkg Path/To/File
```