# How to install Virtual box on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, virtualbox

Can someone help me install Virtual box on my Ubuntu machine? (12.10). I know you can install it from the software centre but I read somewhere that their are more files to add or something? Can someone help me please? All help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you so very much! Have a wonderful day!

- Cody.

Comment: Do you want the Ubuntu packaged version (see [How to install VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/q/239892/88802)) or the virtualbox.org more updated version (see [How do I install the closed source version of VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/q/41478/88802))? What have you tried? And "I read somewhere" - be more specific, please.

Comment: I don't know which one. I installed it from Ubuntu software centre I think. And I seen this site and it was saying that if I get an error do this and I found myself putting a bunch of random things and installing things from my Terminal. I don't know what I installed but hopefully it wont take up space. I know I may seem computer illiterate but i'm not. So sorry for asking this simple question, but i'd rather make sure than have to do it a third time. :$ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Installing the package using the Software Centre provides you with the VirtualBox program itself. You will be able to make new VM's, or add existing ones, and run them with the interface it provides.

There are some hardware features, like USB 2.0, that need additional files in order to be usable. Highly recommended are the [VirtualBox Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html), which provide the guest operating system with drivers that help it run better. Also, you can get the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), which enables features like USB 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

First, open a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T and type in the terminal to update repositories and stuff:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

We want to **really** install VirtualBox now, so when `sudo apt-get update` finishes with no errors, run this command in the terminal (again):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
```

If you have issues, it most likely is beacuse of the VirtualBox kernel. Type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

And again:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The package "dkms" helps if you are having issues with the Virtualbox kernel.

Now you have successfully installed VirtualBox 4.2. Enjoy your virtual operating systems!