# Does Ubuntu support Adobe?

Tags: adobe, photoshop

I have tried Windows, but do not like the upgrades after Windows 7. I want to know if Ubuntu will install programs like Adobe Photoshop and Premiere. Are Linux apps in the dmg format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install photoshop cs6 on ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/530110/how-can-i-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: The real question should be "Does Adobe supports Linux/Ubuntu?"

Comment: _“Are Linux apps in the dmg format?”_ No, the dmg format is used to distribute Mac apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wine (Windows Emulator) to run windows stuff on ubuntu.
Play on linux can help automate the process to getting all dependencies for ya, there are many ways to do it...

Here is one of those ways ;)

http://www.bendangelo.me/install/2014/10/29/installing-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu.html

Lemme know how it works 4 ya ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) means “**W**ine **I**s **N**ot an **E**mulator”.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe products are not designed to work in Linux. But some of Adobe products with more or less success can be run in Ubuntu using wine or PlayOnLinux.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move away from Windows (Congratulations!) as I just did, you are probably best of...

1. find replacement for most Apps on ubuntu level (Notepadqq for Notepad++, Caja as Filemanager naturally, Shotwell isn't too bad now that Picasa is gone for good...)
2. run your legay apps in a [virtual box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239892/how-to-install-virtualbox). The virtual box is free to install. Of course you might need a fresh Windows license to install and whatever software you still need.

Back to Adobe Products: No, at least the Creative Tools don't support Ubuntu. But it is possible to install them inside a Virtual Box. Reportedly it is also possible to [do so using Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530110/how-can-i-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-14-04#) (i.e. Adobe CC), the Windows Emulation/Integration more directly in the Linux Desktop (caveat: 32bit only as of now).

Answer (score 0):

Both PlayOnLinux and Wine support **some** of Adobe products, you might want to give it a try:

Installing PlayOnLinux.

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Installing wine.

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks wine
```