# Tried 3D acceleration lost everything! Black screen

Tags: 12.10, screen, 3d

(Using Virtual Box 4.2.0, Ubuntu 12.10 64bit)

Although the GuestAdditions and 3D acceleration instructions were meant for 4.2.4 and 4.2.6 I wanted to try them for 4.2.0.

Now that I start the VM, I get a black command prompt screen.

As I am new to Linux, I tried to remove the last line from the modules file in `/etc/` by typing

```
sed '$d' < modules
```

This did remove the `vboxvideo` line but I'm still getting the black command screen.

How do I get back the standard visual desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate way to uninstall guest additions from a virtual box guest is to run the script provided:

```
user@guset:$ sudo ./opt/<VirtualBoxAddtions-x.x.xx>/uninstall.sh
```

Replace the `x` placeholders with the ones for your vitualbox version.

Alternatively you can try to install the appropriate version of the guest additions over the existing guest additions. A command line way to do this is outlined here:

- [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)

However it is strongly recommended to upgrade virtual box to the most recent version to be able to run the latest Ubuntu release without issues.

- [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487)

Comment: thanks... it keeps giving me command not found. I tried ./opt/VirtualBoxAdditions-4.2.0/uninstall.sh; I also tried ./opt/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.2.0; also tried without opt/.

Comment: By the way, i also tried sudo -X configure. It lists a bunch of video drivers and then says that "Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices"

Comment: Update: i purged xorg, installed it again, reinstalled intel drivers. Removed .Xauthority. Rebooted. It showed the ubuntu loading screen for a split second then went back to terminal. sudo X -configure keeps giving the message that number of screens does not match number of detected devices.

Comment: All Praise to the Lord! Thank you Takkat! I upgraded to 4.2.6 and installed guest additions using the command line. Desktop is back.

Comment: My saying... recent versions for recent versions. Good you got everything worked out. :)