# Problems runnung VirtualBox in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, virtualization

I am trying to start a VM using VirtualBox, however I get the following errors.

[image: VB error 1]

[image: VB error 2]

I have read many pages on this error (some on this forum) but none of the suggested fixes I have found seem to work. During install, whether using apt-get or a downloaded .deb I get install errors.

[image: Terminal - install errors]

I have tried installing VirtualBox 4.1 and 4.2 with the same results. Some suggestions I read sat to update the headers, where I get more errors.

[image: Terminal - header errors]

I must have some component or other missing from my system that VirtualBox does not like and dependencies that are not getting resolved :(

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Just so you know I've played with virtualBox a lot and found it just had too many issues. Doesn't even support 3D cards in any useful way. VMWare is far superior and I run my 3D steam games with no issues. Not an answer, but a recommend.

Comment: Due to [bug #1081307](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1081307) the virtualbox-ose package won't build its kernel modules in 12.04, or 12.10. Try to install the most recent version from the Oracle repository: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox.

Comment: @Takkat - read the page you linked to. Still not fixed :(   Looked at the install log and it contains the following: `Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.8/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxhost-4.2.8

DKMS: add completed.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:181: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.`  As shown above I'm having a lot of problems with my Kernel headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Virtualbox stopped working again, I found a more permanent fix on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/499059/unable-to-install-virtualbox-specify-kern-dir-directory-installing-vir#_=_). The below commands install the latest headers. The last one updates Virtualbox with the new information.

```
sudo apt-get update

apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

sudo ./etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to get Virtualbox to work so I installed VMware. However after installing and running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, VMware didn’t work :(
But when I opened Virtualbox again, it did! So it worked out the fix for Virtualbox was to install VMware. It must have installed a dependency I needed. At least it works now!