# Missed to Enable 3D acceleration on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I had installed ubuntu 11.10 on virtualbox 4.1.8 over windows 7(64-bit, graphics card ATI Radeon HD 5470) as the host. I was trying to run opengl es programs on ubuntu wherein I faced an error during execution:-

OpenGL Warning: Enable 3d acceleration on your VM. Segmentation Fault

I went to the Display options of my VirtualBox and found 3d acceleration to be disabled. I didn't knew that OpenGL required 3d acceleration to be enabled while installing ubuntu setup and missed doing the same. Now I am unable to Enable it from virtualbox and also I am unable to run Opengl exe's on ubuntu. Kindly help on the same.

Comment: First stop the VM then you will be able to enable it.

Comment: I stopped the VM, saved the state and came out of it and tried to enable but the state being disabled I am not able to enable it

Comment: not sure, I usually shut it down. By `stop` I meant to say shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able enable this time but it threw me following error:- On the Display Page, you enabled 3D acceleration, however 3D acceleration is not working on the current host and you will not be able to start your VM ...

Answer (score 1):

After having shutdown the guest OS in virtualbox we may enable 3D acceleration from the machine settings:

[image]

A guest Ubuntu also needs the guest additions for a virtual 3D graphics driver:

- [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox)

> After having installed the guest additions the guest OS needs a **reboot** for the virtual driver to be loaded.

**Troubleshooting:**

If this failed we may try to reinstall guest additions, and watch out for errors we may get when doing so. Older versions of Virtual Box may be incompatible with either the graphics drivers from the host, or with the guest Ubuntu version. We then have the following options we may have to install a newer version:

- [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox)

In case it still does not work as expected, and we may not have a graphical desktop we may update our OS from the command line as follows:

- Update the guest operation system from command line (hold left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on booting to enter a [root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)) and then run:

  ```
  apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- we may have to install the guest additons again.
- Reboot the VM after an OS update

Comment: I was able enable this time but it threw me following error:- On the Display Page, you enabled 3D acceleration, however 3D acceleration is not working on the current host and you will not be able to start your VM ...

Comment: Of course you need to enable your GPU in the host to be able to use it in the guest. Some host drivers may have issues however.

Comment: I tried to check in the ATI Catalyst Center. but didn't get the option to "Enable GPU", does that mean that my graphics card does not support 3D gaming applications?

Comment: I have zero experience with ATI drivers, and how to enable 3D on Windows. But this may be the issue you have here.