# Why is the Virtualbox not updated in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I have installed VirutalBox from the command line using `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`.
I have version **4.3.10** but on the official website the lateste version is **4.3.18**.
I'v also did the following:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

but still nothing changed.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: Also [How I can properly update VirtualBox to the latest version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276661/how-i-can-properly-update-virtualbox-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: I always install from the Oracle repo to get latest VBox release: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack