# Cannot re-install dkms in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, dkms

I have updated to Ubuntu 13.04 and now I can't run virtual-box I have installed dkms many times please help the problem shown is

```
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858}

Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 182 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file 'virtualbox.li' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'virtualbox.li' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

I think it might be an underlining issue when I updated. I Tried googling it.

Answer (score 4):

Virtual Box does not need DKMS to install but with DKMS the kernel modules will be reinstalled after a kernel upgrade.

After a fresh install it is always a good idea to perform an update of all packages for bugfixes (you have 182 package in the queue there):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then you may have to [load the virtualbox kernel modules](https://askubuntu.com/a/335767/3940) only if you had removed DKMS from the default installation.

If this did not resolve your issue you may have installed an incompatible version of Virtual Box still. This needs to be purged before we can install an up to date version. Removing Virtual Box depends very much on how you had installed it in the first place. You may have to run e.g.

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-<xxx> # replace <xxx> with the version installed
```

After that we can re-install the latest version of virtualbox as depicted in the answer below (I recommend the latest bugfix release from Oracle rather than the version from the repositories):

- [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack)

Comment: hi i still have 182 not upgraded and i tried a purge but the files are still there

Comment: @user186275 Did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` give you any errors?

Comment: @user186275: "the files are still there" -- which files? And what does `dpkg -S filename` tell?

Comment: i tride sudo apt-get dist-upgrade no errors

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to remove wrong repository:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.li
```

Then, upgrade your system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what does this do?

Comment: sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.li
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.li’: No such file or directory
and it is installed

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.li
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Run these commands for update your OS.

The fololowings for install dkms and set for vboxdrv:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Comment: same thing happening

Comment: its coming up that i still have virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb yet i am now running 13.04???

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Takkat](https://askubuntu.com/a/335773/169736) answer, you have a malformed file name in your `/etc/souces.list.d`. The best way to solve this is not deleting the file, but renaming it:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.li /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will take away the `N: Ignoring file 'virtualbox.li' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension` line, and also will upgrade your 183 packages.

Comment: hi i still have 182 not upgraded and i tried a purge but the files are still there

Comment: Some years ago @htorque posted a solution for [bug 611925](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/611925/comments/10) to suppress this IMO non fatal apt notice. The dist-upgrade should not stop from a notice on a bad but ignored file anyway.