# How to change icon of virtual box 5.0

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, icons

Ok i downloaded virtual box 5.0

using the last post on here [How to install Virtualbox from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367248/how-to-install-virtualbox-from-command-line)

the icon for virtual box is just a black screen. virtual box works and all how do i change the icon to the virtualbox logo?

Answer (score 3):

Open your desktop file `virtualbox.desktop` via

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop
```

and have a look at the line

```
Icon=…
```

In my case

```
Icon=virtualbox
```

This means, if your current icon theme has an icon with the name `virtualbox.*`, eg in my case

```
% find /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/ -iname 'virtualbox.*'
/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48x48/apps/virtualbox.svg
```

than the icon of the theme is displayed. And maybe it does not look the way you want.

But the package `virtualbox-5.0` comes with a bunch of icons:

List the icons with:

```
dpkg -L virtualbox-5.0 | grep /usr/share/icons
```

and change your desktop file. I recommend this version:

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/virtualbox.svg
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but i ended up using /usr/share/pixmaps/virtualbox.png 
as the one you provided changed the black image to a blank image. I used the top and now the virtualbox logo is there :) thanks

Comment: Don't thank me :) accept the answer, this means, the answer is valid and your problem is solved ;)