# Nothing is coming up

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I am not able to configure Virtualbox in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my brand new 64 bit PC. Here are some info :
I downloaded and tried by :

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.0-118431~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb
```

It got installed, no error.
Rebooted the PC.

Tried by giving virtualbox in command prompt. No error, no message, but nothing is coming up.

I have written the same issue at [this link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=85356) too and came to know that I have to disable secure boot. I tried same but same issue.

Virtualbox forum says that I should write here.

How do I access Virtualbox?

Comment: have a read : https://askubuntu.com/questions/367248/how-to-install-virtualbox-from-command-line

Comment: Have you tried the version from APT (`sudo apt install virtualbox`)? This should be the preferred way.

Comment: I tried by installing from Ubuntu Software Center option, but the same issue.  Virtualbox icon appears in the left hand side icon tray, but when I clicks on it, screen / headers become dim and nothing. No response, no error. I have to right click and quit

Comment: The vbox forums thread is pretty clear. Your original vbox install seemingly failed because secure boot was enabled.  That means you must clean up from your first attempt, then disable secure boot (which you did), then reininstall properly, then check your logs to ensure install was successful.