# Genymotion not detecting Virtualization engine on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: virtualbox, android-studio, genymotion

I have already installed Oracle VirtualBox and during installing of Genymotion it detected a valid version of VirtualBox. Virtualisation is enabled in BIOS setting of laptop and I have done everything from downloading latest version of VirtualBox and Genymotion to switching to 'Host only netwrok' in network preferences of VirtualBox.

But nothing works for me. This is the error I get while strating Genymotion:

```
In order to work, Genymotion requires VirtualBox to be installed on your computer. You can download the latest version of VirtualBox from www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.

Genymotion log archive has been saved in /home/sourabh/genymotion-log.zip
Please contact Genymotion support for more help.

Virtualization engine not found. Plugin loading aborted.
```

Can anyone tell me what's possibly going wrong?

Edit:

Here is a link to the log file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/jdi51acm136vk0f/genymotion-log.zip

Comment: Which version of virtualbox do you have installed?

Comment: tried with both VirtualBox 5.1.2 and 5.2.6, Genymotion works with neither. Although at installation it displays that a valid version of VB detected.

Comment: Do you mind posting the log here?

Comment: Sure Michael here you go:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/jdi51acm136vk0f/genymotion-log.zip

Comment: Try this: 
    Open Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager
    Go to File -> Preference -> Network -> Hosts-Only Networks,
    Remove all entries under this tab,
    Click OK,
    Restart Genymotion

Comment: There are no entries  under Host Only Network

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your time, but fortunately I have resolved the issue now. In case you are curious I have added below what I did as an answer to this question(https://askubuntu.com/a/999459/742438).

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of different things, I finally resolved the issue by installing VirtualBox directly from the command line(see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/713526/742438)) rather than downloading it from the official website. Then restarted Genymotion and it worked like a charm.