# Installing SuperNova Studio in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, macosx

How to install the file I've just DL on the official site of [Supernova](https://supernova.io/) in Ubuntu or just how to install everything from supernova studio to Ubuntu?

Comment: What kind of file is "the file i've just DL on the official site of Supernova"?  Does Supernova say they support Linux? Are there installation instructions on the Supernova site?

Comment: I think Supernova is only available for Mac!

Answer (score 3):

The application specifies on its home page "Available for Mac OS 10.13+ and newer" and there's no mention of support for any Linux, so you must install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or other virtualization software, then install MacOS X 10.13 or newer in the virtualization software before installing the application.

This requires you [verify that your hardware is capable of running virtualization](https://www.technorms.com/8208/check-if-processor-supports-virtualization); some PCs are not.

Once you have
- verified your CPU and motherboard support virtualization
- you have [installed VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367248/how-to-install-virtualbox-from-command-line) or other virtualization software
- virtually installed MacOS X 10.13 or newer, then
- you can install that application.