# Virtualbox upgrade error "Breaks existing package..."

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, dependencies

Trying to upgrade from Virtualbox 4.2 to 4.3, receiving error

```
"Breaks existing package 'virtualbox-4.2' that conflict: 'virtualbox'..."
```

Answer (score 21):

In order to be able to upgrade Virtual Box to a higher major release (e.g. 4.2.x to 4.3.x) we will have to remove the kernel modules and applications of an old version first. This will **not** affect our virtual machines.

In case you had installed from the [Oracle repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack) you can - after having updated the apt cache - just run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

After upgrading we will also have to download and re-install the extension packs in case we need them. Also it is advisable to update the guest additions in our virtual machines.

Comment: Worked for me +1

Comment: Worked for me in 2019.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is also resolved for VirtualBox-5.0 to Virtualbox-5.1

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.0
```

Then download the virtualbox-5.1 with your Ubuntu version and bit level

Right-click on the file and install via Ubuntu Software Center.

Don't forget to get the extension packs @ www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
Install them via Virtualbox under File/Preferences then Extensions tab on the left.

Every virtual machine will then come back!

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove and then install it with

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-*
```

if there wasn't a package to remove then try to install it:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-5.1.8
```

if there wasn't a package then try to add it by using a PPA:

```
echo 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

According to your distribution, replace `xenial` with `trusty`, `precise`, etc.
You can add these keys with

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

To install VirtualBox, do

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

[Source](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions)

Comment: Solution still valid and working for Ubuntu 16.04, and Virtual Box 5.0→5.1 ... (just to give googlers some assurance)