# How to access a guest OS running in Virtual Box from a different user account

Tags: virtualbox

I installed `virtualbox` in Ubuntu 12.04, in which I installed Windows XP. However I am unable to see VirtualBox on desktop when logging in a different user account and consequently unable to access Windows XP.

How do I access Windows XP running in VirtualBox from another user account on the same PC?

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed it correctly ? try logout/login or a PC reboot. Also, open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and issue this command `apt-cache search virtualbox | grep -i installed` and see(also show us) what returns.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machines are installed in Virtual Box on a per user basis. This means that the virtual machine runs with the user account it was created and started.

To access a running virtual machine from a different user account we have two options:

1. Run an SSH server on the guest to control the guest OS via SSH from a different account (or through the network).
2. Use the desktop remote viewing protocol (RDP) of Virtual Box to have access to the graphical desktop of the guest.

#### Steps to run and access a guest via RDP

1. Install the [Oracle Extension Pack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack).
2. Enable RDP for the guest machine.

   - **Virtual Box Manager**: Enable RDP in *Settings > Display > Remote Display*
     [image]
   - **Command line:**

     ```
     VBoxManage modifyvm "name_of_guest" --vrde on
     ```
3. Start the guest OS from your main user account.
4. Switch to your other user.
5. Run a remote desktop viewer (e.g. **Remmina** which is installed by default).

   - Connect to `localhost:3389` (or another port if defined differently in 2.)
   - Use the name and password of the account from which Virtual Box is running.
     [image]
   - Adjust display geometry or color settings according to your needs.

This way we can access and control a running virtual machine over the network from any remote computer too.