# Install VirtualBox 4.3.12 from terminal

Tags: virtualbox

I want to install `VirtualBox 4.3.12.`  on `Ubuntu 14`, I tried to install it from the terminal, but only this version  :`VirtualBox 4.3` is available .

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package [virtualbox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox) [image: Install virtualbox] maintained in the Ubuntu multiverse repository will install version 4.3.10 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and version 4.3.18 in Ubuntu 14.10.

We can also add the [Oracle repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack) for recent releases and upgrades.

The application version that will be displayed by our package management will be the major release (which is 4.3. at present). Sub-release numbers may not always be displayed.

Packages for older releases are available for download from [Oracle Virtual Box Old Builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds) (choose Ubuntu 13.04 packages for 14.04 or later until a new host platform was built).

Comment: Thanks :) it worked ,I also added the extension pack for the same version !

Answer (score 1):

Go to [the VirtualBox site](http://virtualbox.org) and download whatever version you want, then from the terminal use dpkg to install it.

Here is a [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3) that contains 4.3.12

> sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb

Comment: I found only this version 4.3.18 , how to download the version : 4.3.12 ?