# Migrating VirtualBox VMs

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, macosx

Perhaps not the right forum, and in my opinion more of a comment in addition to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573852/can-i-use-my-virtualbox-vms-on-ubuntu) but as I am unfortunately not yet able to comment, and I'd rather not answer the question and and then have it flagged for not being an answer, I'll just ask a new question.

I'm running Lubuntu 14.10 in a VirtualBox (VB) VM on a Mac OS X 10.10.1 Host. I'm on the verge of doing a clean reinstall of the host system, but as I read [afore mentioned question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573852/can-i-use-my-virtualbox-vms-on-ubuntu_), I wondered, should I follow the same procedure as was mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use my Virtualbox VMs on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/573852/can-i-use-my-virtualbox-vms-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  make the OVF when you go from machine to machine.

Comment: So basically treat a clean reinstall of the host as new machine, Thanks

Comment: Yes, export to another drive. Then put that away. Reinstall the os.  Install virtual box and the guest additions. Then import OVF's from external drive.