# Installing virtualbox in ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

For the past years, I test operating systems using virtualbox using windows. But now I'm currently using ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and trying to install it. I tried to install it today using terminal, but gives me this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package virtualbox-5.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'virtualbox-5.0' has no installation candidate
```

I also check software center, but after installation it gives me an error message so I remove it.

Question:
Is there any another way to install virtualbox? If there is, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack)

Comment: For the newest release we need to install VirtualBox from Oracle, it is not yet available from the Ubuntu resources.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way by far would be getting a hold of the .deb of Virtualbox 5.0. Simply go [to Virtualbox's website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and then get the 5.0.2. build for Ubuntu 14.04. If you're running a 64bit system, then grab the AMD64 deb. If you're using x32, then you will need to grab the i386 build.

[image: File to pick when you're on Virtualbox's website]

After that, simply go the destination that you saved the .deb file and then double click. Ubuntu Software Center will open and you should be able to install it by that way.