# "Package operation failed" in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: virtualbox

This problem occured while installing `virtualbox-5.0_5.0.8-103449~Ubuntu~trusty_i386.deb`, what should I do?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to remove `virtualbox` first: `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox`, however mind that is suggested to install from `apt-get` instead of from a `.deb` package when possible.

Comment: i cannot remove this when i write this command in terminal it shows: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: Did you use `sudo`? `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox`

Comment: yes i used it but it show the error:  E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied) E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: That message should pop up if you're not root. Make sure any instance of Ubuntu Software Center and of Software & Updates is closed before retrying, despite the message suggesting else probably something is using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 3):

When upgrading Virtual Box to a newer major release version (e.g. from 4.x to 5.x) we need to remove the older version first to be able to proceed.

Removal of a package depends on how you had installed it. In most cases you can use the **Software Center** to remove installed packages. In case you had installed Virtual Box from the repositories it is the package `virtualbox` you will have to remove.

If a package is not listed there, or if we had installed it from another source we may also issue the following command in a terminal (for removal of virtualbox 4.0):

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-4.0
```

Note that your settings and your existing virtual machines will stay untouched, they will not be removed.

After that we can safely re-install Virtual Box from a DEB file we had downloaded, or by adding the [Oracle repository to our sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack), which will always install the most recent version (at present 5.0.8). After upgrading Virtual Box we should also upgrade the Guest Additions in our virtual machines.