# How to upgrade Virtualbox 5.1 to current version (Win10 Guest)?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, virtualbox, windows-10

Since I upgraded my virtual Win7 to Win10 yesterday, everything seems to work fine, but sometimes windows and menus etc. appear strange, like there is some graphic issue. First I changed the settings of the virtual machine from Win7 x64 to Win10 x64.

Then I looked for an upgrade-tutorial (for the current Virtualbox version 6.0.2) and I found tons of tutorials for older versions and every tutorial seems to have different terminal commands, which is difficult for me to know which steps could be right or wrong.

I also thought about update only the ExtensionsPack (my current 5.1-version is not supported anymore) to 5.2 or 6.0.2, but I dont know if this would help at all.

How can I prevent completely re-install VirtualBox? Unfortunately I couldnt just make a new Win10 guest-system, which always got stuck in installation, so I used my Win7 and the upgrade worked fine. Now I fear I have to install all the three again.

Any suggestions, help, alternatives? Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 5):

For me always the easiest VirtualBox install was with the [Oracle Repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack).

- add that repository with

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib"
  sudo apt update
  ```
- [remove previous VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692982/virtualbox-failed-to-install-after-upgrade-to-15-10) release versions to be able to upgrade to VirtualBox 6.0:

  ```
  sudo apt remove virtualbox*
  ```

  Your virtual machines will not be deleted by this.
- install virtualbox from the Oracle repository:

  ```
  sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0
  ```

  This will install the last update of the 6.0. release (which presently would be 6.0.2). Later updates with bugfixes will be automatically offered and installed by our package management until releas cycle 7.0. will be present which again would require to remove 6.0 versions.

The virtual machines you had created will remain untouched and freely accessible but you will have to [upgrade the guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) and extension packs, only if you had used them.

Comment: Agree with this. In fact, the install of virtualbox-6.0 automatically removed the -5 install I had.

Comment: I followed these steps, at the last one I get this error output: `E: Package virtualbox-6.0 cant be found.` and `E: no virtualbox-6.0 package can be found`.

Comment: IT WORKS! I had to `sudo apt-get update` again, after this the `install virtualbox-6.0` command works! Thank you so much, you saved me hours of frustration. :)

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the previous version of VirtualBox and its configuration but keep the Virtual Hard disks

`sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox`

`sudo rm ~/.config/VirtualBox/ -Rf`

Update and upgrade the system

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Setup Apt Repository

`wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- |
 sudo apt-key add -`

`wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo
 apt-key add -`

Add PPA

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib"`

Install VirtualBox

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0`