# How to upgrade VirtualBox in 14.04 Native using CLI

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, virtualbox

My Computer is running 14.04 native. 
I have Virtualbox so I can use windows 10 and kali linux. 
I have been receiving alerts at virtualbox startup. 
To determine what version I currently have I did: 
$ VBoxManage --version
5.0.14r105127
I downloaded the latest version from Oracle site. Here is the downloaded file.
virtualbox-5.0_5.0.16-105871-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb

I do not know how to proceed from here. I am also concerned because I do not want to lose the existing virtual computers because I have been using them constantly and have very important information there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just double click the file to open it in Software center where you can click install. Your existing virtual machines aren't affected.

Answer (score 0):

To install the downloades package from the commad line you can cd to the directory it is stored and run the package installer from there:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.16-105871-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb
```

You will not lose your exisiting virtual machines by this but you will have to download and re-install an Extension Pack if you had it installed before. You will also have to upgrade your guest additions to the current release.

To ease upgrading of Virtual Box Oracle maintains an own repository that will take care to install Virtual Box, and provide updates as soon as they are available. How to install this repository see e.g.:

- [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack)

or follow the nice [guide from Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).