# Virtual box dependency issue

Tags: virtualbox, dpkg

I am newbie in ubunut and I am really confused in the installation of virtual box for college assignments. I am asking this on a new thread intentionally even though many existing threads try to resolve an almost identical issue. 
I have tried almost everything given on the identical issues but I seem to be getting anywhere and I am still getting this message after running.

```
sudo dpkg -i  virtualbox-5.0_5.0.20-106931-Ubuntu-trusty_i386.deb
```

I am getting this error.

```
Unpacking virtualbox-5.0 (5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~trusty) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-5.0:
 virtualbox-5.0 depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2).
 virtualbox-5.0 depends on libpython2.7 (>= 2.7).
 virtualbox-5.0 depends on libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11).
 virtualbox-5.0 depends on psmisc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `sudo apt-get install -f`

If that doesn't work, try installing GDebi - a graphical installer for Deb packages - that'll manage everything.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it. It did not work.

Comment: @ArafatK Then try installing GDebi - it can install deb packages graphically.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju you might want to include that into your answer.

Comment: @Videonauth done

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading and installing the `.deb` package, you may try to use the Oracle-VirtualBox repository to install the software.

- You may check: [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack)