# Genymotion and virtualbox not starting after updating ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm sorry if it's been asked before but I could not find it here.
I did the last install updates for Ubuntu 14.04 like always. and when it failed to start the Vbox and genymotion i usually ran the command `$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and it would solve the problem but this time it doesn't work at all and I'm getting the following errors...

```
 ~$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-5.0.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/5.0.2/build/make.log for more information.
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

Could someone help me please? I'm so lost and hopeless
Thank you very much

Comment: You may have to upgrade virtualbox to a newer release to support kernel 4.4. - present release version is at 5.1.6.

Comment: Virtualbox can only compile on kernel >= 4.3 from version 5.0.6. From your errors we see that your kernel is 4.4. but virtualbox is version 5.0.2. only. So it may just need an upgrade.

Comment: Can you help me update it? And if do. won't i lose my virtual machines i have?

Comment: I'd go with the official Oracle repository. See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940 you won't lose your existing VMs.

Comment: Sorry I have too little time for a chat guidance but it should not be too hard if you follow the guide I posted above. Before you are able to install `virtualbox-5.1` you will have to purge `virtualbox-5.0`. You may have to also upgrade the extension pack if installed, and your existing machines will need an update of their guest additions.

Comment: I just tried to install Vbox 5.1 i go tthis error...    Breaks existing package 'virtualbox-5.0' that conflict: 'virtualbox' .But the '/Tmp/mozilla_none0/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.6-110634~Ubuntu~trusty~amd64-1.deb' provides it via: 'virtualbox'

Comment: Yeah that's expected. Purge 5.0 to be able to install 5.1.

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me. But will i lose my vm mashines and setting if i purge?

Comment: Or can i just downgrade my kernel so it would all work like it used to be? i have many stuff on my machines that if i lose i will be dead. i can't risk it much. thanks again

Comment: No, you won't lose anything- I do that since 2.0

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. will you please stay with me here ? i just ran the command " sudo apt purge virtualbox" then i retried to install 5'1 through software center. still same error. i think i need to reboot?

Comment: Hello again Takkat. It wont let me install vbox 5.1, even tho i purged the vbox 5.0 but still when i click on vbox it comes up. How else can i get rid of it?  thanks

Comment: Nvm just fixed it. i had to add the version to purge too. like virtualbox5.0