# Problem with dependencis where try to install virtualbox5.1

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, dpkg

I know that it should be easy, but I'm new in Ubuntu, so please help:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.10-112026-Ubuntu-yakkety_amd64.deb 
Wybieranie wcześniej niewybranego pakietu virtualbox-5.1.
(Odczytywanie bazy danych ... 301555 plików i katalogów obecnie zainstalowanych.)
Przygotowywanie do rozpakowania pakietu virtualbox-5.1_5.1.10-112026-Ubuntu-yakkety_amd64.deb ...
Rozpakowywanie pakietu virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.10-112026~Ubuntu~yakkety) ...
dpkg: problemy z zależnościami uniemożliwiają skonfigurowanie pakietu virtualbox-5.1:
 virtualbox-5.1 zależy od libqt5core5a (>= 5.6.0~beta); jednakże:
  Wersją libqt5core5a:amd64 w systemie jest 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2.
 virtualbox-5.1 zależy od libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.6.0~beta); jednakże:
  Wersją libqt5widgets5:amd64 w systemie jest 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2.
 virtualbox-5.1 zależy od libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0); jednakże:
  Wersją libqt5x11extras5:amd64 w systemie jest 5.5.1-3build1.

dpkg: błąd przetwarzania pakietu virtualbox-5.1 (--install):
 problemy z zależnościami - pozostawianie nieskonfigurowanego
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu systemd (229-4ubuntu12)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu ureadahead (0.100.0-19)...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1)...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu mime-support (3.59ubuntu1)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1)...
Wystąpiły błędy podczas przetwarzania:
 virtualbox-5.1
```

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What is your Ubuntu release? The DEB package you have is for Ubuntu 16.10 only. Please download a package built for your Ubuntu release, or consider to install from the Oracle repository: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads. Also see http://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940

Answer (score 0):

I cant read your language, but usually when I have problems like this, it is because of dependencies, and you can solve it with "sudo apt-get -f install", which installs the dependencies together with your package.

Answer (score 0):

Download the corresponding version of the package from : [VirtualBox download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

[64](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.10/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.10-112026~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb) or [32](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.10/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.10-112026~Ubuntu~xenial_i386.deb)

Try to install with **Ubuntu software center**. Then in terminal type vbox