# Can't solve problem with virtual box

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, genymotion

I am pretty new to Ubuntu. I had been using genymotion for the past 2-3 days. When I tried to start it today, it indicated something is wrong with the virtualbox. I had it installed from the repos. I have uninstalled it, then reinstalled it again from the repos, then uninstalled it again and then reinstalled using the .deb from the VirtualBox site. Tried installing dkms, nothing happened. Trying to start Virtual Box I am getting this message,

```
      WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module available for the current kernel (4.4.0-65-generic) or it failed to load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

       sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

       You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Trying to run sudo /sbin/vboxconfig, I get this:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.

 This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).

  Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic
  (The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
   apt-get install linux-headers-generic
   vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.

  This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).

   Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic

  (The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)

  apt-get install linux-headers-generic

  There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run /sbin/vboxconfig as root.
```

The contents of /var/log/vbox-install.log is:

```
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR <directory> and run Make again.  Stop.

Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR <directory> and run Make again.  Stop.

Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR <directory> and run Make again.  Stop.

Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR <directory> and run Make again.  Stop.

Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR <directory> and run Make again.  Stop.

Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR <directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

And running apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic, I get:

```
  Package linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.

  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

  E: Package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: First, how are you installing virtualbox ? Second, did you read the message ? It gives clear instructions. `apt-get install linux-headers-generic` , gave you that message more then once, so, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` and then try again to install vbox. Vbox is in the repos , and KVM and similar are supported out of the box as alternates to vbox.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen   Of course I did try all of those. But it didn't fix it. I installed first from the repos, then the .deb from the site.  And gennymotion requires virtualbox, kvm won't do, I think

Comment: Of course you did what ? You need to update your question with 1. How are you installing vbox ? and what commands you ran to try to fix the problem. See also - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Sorry updated the comment.

Comment: Update the question, not everyone reads the comments. See also the link I gave you and tell us where you got what version of vbox and tried installing it how .....

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack

Comment: That is NOT the command I asked you to run. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` then try installing vbox again

Comment: Can you please reboot and run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Comment: I have tried it. It doesn't solve the problem. It was the first thing I did.

Comment: Did you reboot ? You really should update the question with these details. My guess is that your kernel updated and so you need to reboot. If it fails after a reboot, post the output of `uname -r` and try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: I have rebooted. I have tried to reboot after trying to fix broken packages from recovery mode. The oupput of uname -r is linux-4.4.0-65-generic

Comment: If you have updated and run sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic and it still fails with the error message you gave you will have to file a bug report against linus-headers-generic and try booting an older kernel .

Comment: Yeah. It works with an older kernel.

Comment: The problem is that the kernel headers are not yet available for the new kernel. Wait a few days and try again or file a bug report, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occour when the module is not loaded.
Even if you don't use Arch Linux, you can still read this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Load_the_VirtualBox_kernel_modules

So, just try:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

or reboot your computer.

Comment: In Ubuntu that error is because the headers are not installed so modprobe will not work (yet) . The arch linux documents are awesome, but with Ubuntu use the ubuntu docs - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox

Comment: Hmmm, then update your system using "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade", reinstall the headers, virtualbox and reboot / use modprobe.

Comment: On ubuntu, to install the headers, you need `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` as in the message given to the user in the output on the command s/he ran, as in my comments. With Ubuntu see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation and https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: "Package linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.

  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

  E: Package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic' has no installation candidate". That's because kernel headers were deleted from the repos because there is a new kernel release avaliable. So, s/he must update the whole system before installing the headers.

Comment: @ThomasWilliam But sudo apt-get dist-upgrade says there's nothing to upgrade, same as upgrade.

Comment: Can you please reboot and run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Comment: I have tried it. It says the linux-headers are newest version (linux-headers-4.4.0-64.8-generic). But my kernel version is linux-4.4.0-65

Comment: If you have updated and run sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic and it still fails with the error message you gave you will have to file a bug report against linus-headers-generic and try booting an older kernel .

Comment: The headers sometimes lag a few days, but you will need to file a bug report.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Where should I file the bug report?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/  and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug?no-redirect=

Comment: It is against the new kernel, just report kernel headers are not available