# Upgrade to 17.04 kills virtualbox

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, 17.04

I just upgraded to 17.04 and Virtualbox is dead.
I tried

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

and that failed. Then I went to www.ubuntuupdates.org
and downloaded a fresh copy of 5.1, which is the latest release supported.

I press the <kbd>Install</kbd> button on the software installer and it just sits there.

Does anybody else have similar problems? Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried installing it with Gdebi?

Comment: @Ilan Is there any error showing up? add them to your question. also add the output of `dpkg -l virtualbox | grep ^i`.

Comment: Any reason why you did not download/install directly from Oracle? They also maintain a repository for a [more convenient install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gdebi worked for me

all you need to do is install it and open your `.deb` files through it

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Comment: didn't worked for me

Comment: @NickDeGreek what  did you actually try?

Comment: The "sudo apt-get install gdebi" fails. I had to purge the old installation and re-install from scratch. The old one was working perfectly before I upgrade to 17.04

Comment: @NickDeGreek and did you open the `deb` file with Gdebi?

Comment: Yes I did installed the deb files using gdebi but it still vbox wasn't running properly. I had to purge the old one and reinstall it. After that, vbox started working again

Comment: @NickDeGreek I tackled the **installation** issue in my answer, clearly your issue was a little bit different, you can also post your own answer