# Unable to install Teamviewer 12 or Excaqvision DEB files

Tags: 17.04, teamviewer

I was able to install and use both the TeamViewer 12 DEB and exacqvision for Linux in Ubuntu 14.04 but I cannot install in Ubuntu 17.04.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you attempt to install it with `sudo dpkg -i file.deb`, what error does it throw?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade to 17.04 kills virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904640/upgrade-to-17-04-kills-virtualbox)

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Nice answer. I have nominated the question you linked to to be reopened because it has an accepted answer and it was closed on a technicality. Perhaps you would consider doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Install:

```
wget https://downloadeu8.teamviewer.com/download/version_12x/teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb
```

Maybe got error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer:i386
```

Info:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep team
iU  teamviewer:i386
```

Fix:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install
```

Info:

```
dpkg -l | grep team
ii  teamviewer:i386
```