# How do I Install the latest Virtual Box from the command line?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, virtualbox

How do I install (for example with `apt-get install` command) the new version of virtual box 5.1.22 (while i have 5.1.18) with command line? What commands do I use?

Comment: Here is how to [install and keep up to date from the Oracle repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use gdebi for this:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

Then you can install any debian installer file with ...

```
sudo gdebi virtualbox-5.1.22.deb
```

Advantage: this will also check and install dependencies.

Comment: do i have to download the package first?

Comment: Yes. and all dependencies that are not default.

Answer (score 0):

just type command `sudo apt install virtualbox` and it will upgrade your Virtualbox.also command `sudo apt sudo apt upgrade virtualbox` will do the same

Comment: Are you sure? That should ONLY work if he has a PPA with 5.1.22 in it.

Comment: i just tried  this in my terminal and then post these commands and have just installed Ubuntu mate 16.04 which is very clean with no additional PPA

Comment: Shall i try this or there will be any drawback?

Comment: No. there are no drawback.but it is simple way.if it doesn't work then try other answer.