# Running Windows in Ubuntu like running Ubuntu in Windows via Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

Ubuntu is working perfectly in virtual box in windows machine.

Is there a virtual box equivalent is available in ubuntu to run windows operating system?

Thanks.

Comment: There is virtualbox installable from Ubuntu Software or [from the Oracle repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack). You can run the same virtual machines in any host OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several.  VirtualBox and VMWare are both available for Ubuntu, or if you prefer something FOSS you can use KVM in Ubuntu, and all of these are capable of running Windows VM's inside Ubuntu.

Comment: Support for KVM tends to be a bit better, IMHO, and KVM + spice is fast. VBox is a good choice. VMWare - take care to use supported ubuntu hosts and sometimes there are problems with vmware and kernel updates.

Comment: @Panther I switched over the KVM/QEMU a while ago, and have not regretted it one little bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is also WINE.

WINE is a command shell that allows many Windows applications to run in Linux without the overhead of a VM. Unlike VMs and Emulators which usually take a large speed hit, WINE also runs at near native speed.

Comment: Yes, but wine is more complicated and less reliable than KVM/virtualbox/VMWare and many applications do not work on wine. Photoshop for example.

Comment: @panther -- setting up a VM is more complicated than setting up wine. Wine allows direct system access, the VM does not, and wine is very reliable